# New-Object not assigned to a variable PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I apologize in advanced if this is a stupid question, but I was wondering is there a way to find objects created in a session of PowerShell that are not assigned to a variable?

for instance:

```
New-Object -TypeName WinSCP.Session
```

that would create an object, but with it not assigned to a variable, how do I .Dispose() it?  is there a way?  Or does that Object just remain until I close the PSSession?

I know with this particular class, there is a default timeout of 1 minute, but if that where not the case, what would happen?

Comment: What's provoking the question? If you don't assign it to a variable, the .NET framework will automatically dispose of it.

Comment: this all makes sense, and I was on the right track, the reason I asked is because I am working on a wrapper for WinSCP, and I wrote a function that returns a WinSCP.Session Object, however, if you don't assign it to a variable, you cannot manipulate it,  IE New-WinSCPSession -HostName "myHost".  but if you assign it to a variable, IE $x = New-WinSCPSession -HostName "myHost", it can then be manipulated with $x.GetFiles().  I was just trying to protect against Undispossed objects.  Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've run the command in the console, the object is gone, and can't be retrieved. I don't know what PowerShell does with disposable objects when they're no longer being used. If you close and re-open your console, the non-managed resources used by `WinSCP.Session` will be removed from memory when the PowerShell process closes.